# Почему не используется scenario?

Tags: php, yii2, mvc, yii, php7

Почему большинство `Yii2` разработчиков не используют `scenario` для авторизации / регистрации пользователя, а вместо этого создают отдельные модели?

Так, например: [тут](https://github.com/samdark/yiipowered/blob/master/models/LoginForm.php) реализована модель для авторизации, [тут](https://github.com/samdark/yiipowered/blob/master/models/SignupForm.php) модель для регистрации, а [это](https://github.com/samdark/yiipowered/blob/master/models/User.php) сама модель `User`. Так почему бы не объединить все в одну модель? К примеру, в модель `User` **добавить** в функцию `rules` что-то вроде:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        // SCENARIO ДЛЯ РЕГИСТРАЦИИ
        ['username', 'filter', 'filter' => 'trim', 'on' => self::SCENARIO_REGISTER],
        ['username', 'required', 'on' => self::SCENARIO_REGISTER],
        ['username', 'unique', 'targetClass' => User::class, 'message' => Yii::t('app', 'This username has already been taken.'), 'on' => self::SCENARIO_REGISTER],
        ['username', 'string', 'min' => 2, 'max' => 255, 'on' => self::SCENARIO_REGISTER],

        ['email', 'filter', 'filter' => 'trim', 'on' => self::SCENARIO_REGISTER],
        ['email', 'required', 'on' => self::SCENARIO_REGISTER],
        ['email', 'email', 'on' => self::SCENARIO_REGISTER],
        ['email', 'unique', 'targetClass' => User::class, 'message' => Yii::t('app', 'This email address has already been taken.'), 'on' => self::SCENARIO_REGISTER],

        ['password', 'required', 'on' => self::SCENARIO_REGISTER],
        ['password', 'string', 'min' => 6, 'on' => self::SCENARIO_REGISTER],
    ];


    // SCENARIO ДЛЯ АВТОРИЗАЦИИ
    [['username', 'password'], 'required', 'on' => self::SCENARIO_LOGIN],
    ['password', 'validatePassword', 'on' => self::SCENARIO_LOGIN],
}
```

И таким образом, вместо создания двух новых моделей (для авторизации и регистрации), у нас весь код получится в одной модели `User`. Просто нужно будеть указывать какой `scenario` в данный момент используется. Разве так не правильнее?

Comment: Например чтобы не раздувать модель как бегемота)) чтобы модель отвечала (по SOLID) только за одно что-то а не за всё сразу

Comment: @АлексейШиманский тогда в каких ситуациях разумно использовать `scenario`?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский [вот](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/structure-models#scenarios) например, в официльном справочнике по Yii приведен пример, в котором `scenario` используется как раз для разделения авторизации и регистрации. Выходит, что так все-же правильнее делать, раз так разработчики рекомендуют?) Или я не прав?

Comment: " каких ситуациях разумно использовать scenario" --- Сложно сказать однозначно. Только на практике относительно задач некоторые вопросы решаются. Также зависит от того, что удобно самим разрабам. К одной задаче вообще можно несколько приёмов применить... например для каждого экшна вообще можно сделать отдельный класс... тоже вполне бывает удобно

Comment: Рекомендации - не строго обязательно. Можешь делать. Можешь не делать. Они скорее привели пример использования сценария. Они могли привести пример и просто на кошках. Это не важно. Важно донести суть сценариев. А правильно в зависимости от ситуации может быть разное. Единого подхода к решению одной и той же проблемы может не быть. Например чтение из базы без индексов - работает вполне себе и так. При больших объемах информации и операции - уже умрёт. Поэтому для оптимизации вешают индексы... Однако если вешать индексы на всё подряд - это только усугубит ситуацию, а неулучшит ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

Не стоит путать модель и форму - они служат разным целям. Для примера, у тебя есть форма входа в админку в которой кроме логина и пароля требуется ввести капчу. Правила проверки капчи не относятся непосредственно к модели User. Можно было бы использовать DynamicModel, но в сообществе Yii2 принято создавать класс формы наследуемой от Model.

Использовать модель для указания правил валидации формы - это плохое архитектурное решение т.к. твоя модель становится зависимой от этих форм : тебе придется каждый раз изменять модель при их изменении/удалении. Кроме того, как показано на примере с капчей, твоя модель будет содержать правила для полей которые не являются её атрибутами. Если еще не знаком, то почитай о SOLID принципах проектирования.